# Fossil SCM: Merge leafs back to trunk

Tags: dvcs, fossil

I have been working for some time with Fossil SCM but I still see something I don't quite get.

[image: fossil timeline]

In the screenshot you can see that I have two Leaves that are present in the repository, but sadly I can't find the way to merge them back into trunk (is annoying to have the 'Leaf' mark in all my commits).

I had Leaves before and I normally merged them by doing

```
fossil update trunk
fossil merge <merged_changeset_id>
```

But now I just get the message:

```
fossil: cannot find a common ancestor between the current checkout and ...
```

Update: This repository is a complete import from a git repository, I'm gonna try to reproduce the exception.

Comment: have you by chance shunned anything?

Comment: No, I haven't done anything like that, just import from a git-repo.

Answer (score 1):

ravenspoint is right---using `--baseline BASELINE`,
especially using the initial empty commit
of the branch you are trying to merge into
will link your independent branches into a single graph.

You can also hide the leaves you do not want to see from the timeline through the web ui, or mark them as closed.

Updated, 2017-01-12: this approach stopped working for me at some point.
I get "lack both primary and secondary files" errors when I try it now. I suspect this is dependent on the schema, possibly the changes associated with Fossil 1.34

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

--baseline BASELINE     Use BASELINE as the "pivot" of the merge instead
                          of the nearest common ancestor.  This allows
                          a sequence of changes in a branch to be merged
                          without having to merge the entire branch.